# The easiest way to plot two columns vs together

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

If I have two columns of data 1 and 2
`col1={{1},{2},{3}}`and `col2={{4},{5},{6}}`
 which each of them has 3 rows for example, what is the easiest way to plot col1 versus col2?

Comment: `ListLinePlot[Join[col1, col2, 2]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
col1 = {{1}, {2}, {3}} // Flatten;
col2 = {{4}, {5}, {6}} // Flatten;
ListPlot[Transpose[{col1, col2}]]
```

yielding the following plot:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot :)